# Фильтр чисел в datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms, filter

Доброго времени суток, реализовал телефонный справочник(огромное спасибо друзьям с stackoverflow & cyberforum), Осталось сделать фильтр, который будет искать и по числам.

Заранее спасибо)

```
 using System;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.Data.OleDb;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Reflection;

 namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
 {
public partial class Main_Form : Form
{
    public Main_Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    DataSet da = new DataSet();
    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

    private static string Excel_Load() //Берем файл excel из папки сборки !!!(Заменить на серверную)
    {
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        path = Path.Combine(path, "textfortest.xlsx");
        string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + @"; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=Yes;ImportMixedTypes=Text;TypeGuessRowsIMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0""";
        return ConnectionString;

    }

    private void DataView(DataSet da,string filtre ="")//Таблица с фильтром
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = da.Tables[0];


        DataTableCollection tables = da.Tables;
        DataView view1 = new DataView(tables[0]);
        view1.RowFilter = filtre;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = view1;

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 65;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 200;
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Width = 55;
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Width = 70;
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].Width = 205;
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].Width = 205;
        dataGridView1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

    private void DateBase() //База данных
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Excel_Load());

        string Strcmd = "select * from [List$A1:G350]";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(Strcmd, conn);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            da.Clear();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(da);

            DataView(da);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) // Запуск формы
    {
        DateBase();
        DataView(da);                 
    }

    private void pictureBox2_MouseClick(object sender, EventArgs e) //Обновление
    {
        DataView(da);
        textBox1.Clear();
    }


    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) //Фильтр
    {
         string rr = "(Должность LIKE  '" + textBox1.Text + "*') OR (ФИО LIKE  '" + textBox1.Text + "*') OR (Подразделение LIKE  '" + textBox1.Text + "*')";
        DataView(da, rr);
    }

    private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: А где сам вопрос? Ошибка в коде? Что не получилось-то?

Comment: @EllaSvetlaya мы пишем в textbox, он возвращает стринг, есть фильтр для DataView, здесь подходит LIKE, но с числами оно не работает

Comment: Числовое поле надо предварительно преобразовать в текст. Добавила пример в вопросе дубликате.